# Mouse back and forward thumb buttons not working

Tags: vmware, 19.04, input-devices

Mouse back and forward thumb buttons are not working on Ubuntu 19.04 using vmware 15.1. I don't think it's the VM though because the buttons do work with a Windows VM. And of course on the host computer, too. I have a AULA Ghost Shark gaming mouse.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Extra mouse buttons not working in virtualization (VMware/VirtualBox, ubuntu host)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/439836/extra-mouse-buttons-not-working-in-virtualization-vmware-virtualbox-ubuntu-hos)

Answer (score 3):

add this to .vmx file of your Vm(just append it to the end of the file):

```
mouse.vusb.enable = "TRUE"
mouse.vusb.useBasicMouse = "FALSE"
usb.generic.allowHID = "TRUE"
```

make sure the VM and vmware is turned off(because if you will change it while VM is on it will not affect and the file changes will override when you close the VM - that what happened to me).

Comment: Would you be able to add more details about how you found out these were the settings? what do they mean individually? is this somewhere hidden in the vmware docs?

Comment: Don't remember, but it took few hours of search